# Scroll to a class on button click - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page with a frame having lot of lines and a button "Next". On clicking Next Button, I should be able to navigate to a paragraph having orange color. All the paragraphs having orange color will be of same class.

That means, on page load I should be able to navigate to 3rd paragraph. On another click I should go to 6th paragraph and so on..

I tried to use document.getelementsbyclassname(). But I was not able to write logic to navigate to that particular location. Please help me out. [image]

Comment: Can you write here (http://jsfiddle.net/) what you have tried?

Comment: `navigate to` you mean to say `scroll to` next paragraph with class `orange`

Comment: @Amit Soni : Yes..we need to scroll to that paragraph..

Comment: @Rupam Datta : I dont have access to jsfiddle from my machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this , like this

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RBvu8/1/)**

```
$("p:first").addClass("active");

$(document).on("click","#ip",function(){
    if($("p.orange:last").hasClass("active")){

           var topVal = $("p:first").offset().top;

           $("html body").animate({
                scrollTop:topVal
            },500,function(){
                $("p").removeClass("active");
                $("p:first").addClass("active");
            });
       }
    else{
        var nextElem = $("p.active").nextAll("p.orange:first");

        var topVal = nextElem.offset().top;
        //alert(topVal);
        $("html body").animate({
            scrollTop:topVal
        },500,function(){
            $("p").removeClass("active");
            nextElem.addClass("active");
        });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First, create a variable called, lets's say, **number** which stores which paragraph we currently need to scroll to. Like 1st, 2nd, etc. When the page loads, it's value will be **1**.

```
var number=1;
```

The next step is to add ids to all the orange paragraph. The first paragraph gets id **orange1**, the second one gets id **orange2** and so on. You can either do this manually or if there are too many paragraphs you can try adding it by looping or something like that.

Now assuming the **Next** button has an id called 'button' you can add this code:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#orange'+number).offset().top
    }, 1000);

    number++;
});
```

Now, whenever you click on the **Next** button, the page should scroll to the correct paragraph. Hope this helps.